# Downloading an image using cURL on a website with security checks

Tags: php, curl

I need to download an image from a remote location using cURL. When i visite the link manualy, the image opens fine in my browser. But I can't seem to find a way to get my code working. I think the remote server has a few extra checks to protect the image ... so I am trying hard to make my request look as humain as possible but I can't seem to get it right.

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
$headers[] = 'Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3';
$headers[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
$headers[] = 'Host: host.com';
$headers[] = 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
$headers[] = 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 99);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$raw=curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Use your browser's *Network* console to inspect the request made for the image and compare it to your PHP request. Also, I wouldn't set the `Host` header

Comment: Go in Chrome's network inspector, find the HTTP request, and right-click and "copy as curl". That'll give you all the params your browser is sending.

Comment: Thats what I did and finished with the above header array but it's still not working ...

Comment: Then perhaps they're blocking known IP address ranges of hosting providers, to prevent scraping. Seems clear they don't want you accessing their site - you might consider respecting it.